# Google Cloud Datastore delete all entities within namespace for a given key

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

We are using Google Cloud Datastore as a database. I encountered problem since in some entities I have references to other entities and while deleting one entity I also need to delete reference to it inside another entities. Is there a mechanism to delete entities of given kind and key in Google Datastore within namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no direct way to do, you can index the reference and delete it with a query after you delete the entity